# Only display part of string after a certain word in Java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to only display data after a certain static word (in)

Example:

```
String jobName = job.getDescription();
```

returns the following:

```
XYZ/LMNOP in ABCEFG
```

I only want the data after the "in" in this scenario. However the XYZ/LMNOP is different in almost every case so I cannot simply call out that section of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) in the `String` class.

```
String jobName = job.getDescription();
String[] parts = jobName.split("in"); { "XYZ/LMNOP", "ABCEFG" }
String before = parts[0]; // XYZ/LMNOP 
String after = parts[1]; // ABCEFG
```

Answer (score 0):

Find index of "in" in the string and then use the string from that particular index+3 to last.

```
int k = p.indexOf("in");
System.out.println(p.substring(k+3));
```

index+3 because `"i", "n" , " "` are 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
String search = " in ";
String d = job.getDescription();
d = d.substring(d.indexOf(search) + search.length(), d.length());
```

Outputs, given the inputs:

> [find something in a string] -> [a string]
>   [finding something in a string] -> [a string] // note findINg, that does not match

The search key can be changed to simply `in` if desired, or left as is to match the question posted to avoid an accidental `in` in a word.

If you so choose, you can also use `.toLower()` on *getDescription()* if you want to be case insensitive when matching the word `in` as well.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand your strings **possible** data values. If it is always `<some_text> in <some_text>` then there are muliple ways as other users have mentioned.

Here is another way, whih is bit simpler

```
String[] strArray = job.getDescription().split(" "); //splits array on spaces
System.out.println(strArray[2]);
```